# Filters of Boolean algebras which are Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

Looking at some filters generated by elements of a finite Boolean algebra I have the impression that many/most/all of them are by themselves Boolean algebras (at least I didn't stumble upon a counterexample). For example the [filter generated by $\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1,3\rbrace$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUpset.svg) in the power set algebra of $\lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace$ is isomorphic to the power set algebra of $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ - with $\lbrace 1\rbrace$ instead of $\emptyset$ being the minimal element and accordingly 
$\lbrace 1,3,4\rbrace$ instead of $\lbrace 3,4\rbrace$ being the negation of $\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$.

My question is:

> Which filters of which Boolean algebras are by themselves Boolean
>   algebras?

If the answer is *not* "all filters of all Boolean algebras" what is the smallest/simplest counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Fréchet (cofinite) filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_filter) on $\mathbb{N}$ is not a Boolean algebra, the simplest reason being that there is no unique bottom element.

Furthermore, a filter $F$ in a Boolean algebra $B$ is itself a Boolean algebra (under the inherited join and meet operations) iff it is principal.

> ($\Rightarrow$) If $F \subseteq B$ is the filter $\{ x \in B : a \leq x \}$ for some $a \in B$, it is then easy to show that $F$ is a Boolean algebra with bottom element $a$.
>   ($\Leftarrow$) If $F \subseteq B$ is a filter which is also a Boolean algebra under the inherited meet and join operations, consider the bottom element $a$ of $F$.  It follows that $F = \{ x \in B : a \leq x \}$, and so is principal.

Comment: The cofinite filter is named after Fréchet? I had no idea.

Comment: Wasn't it "finitely generated" some minutes ago? Is "finitely generated" not enough - or equivalent with "principal" (= generated by one element)?

Comment: @HansStricker:  Yes, I changed "finitely generated" to principal because they are the same.  If $F$ is generated by $a_1 , \ldots , a_n$, then it is also generated by their meet.